# How find indexOf / occurrence in jquery

Tags: javascript, syntax

How find indexOf / occurrence of  " and \ in given string.using jquery

```
if(str.indexOf('"') == -1) || (str.indexOf("\") == -1){ console.log('true')}else{console.log('false');}
```

I tried the above but it shows an error.

Comment: can you show your `str`?

Comment: str is variable  i just need to check if "\ exist the position of of "\ can be any where or maybe no exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple problems.

You need to escape the `\` character that you are passing to your second `indexOf` call. Right now, the `\"` part is getting parsed as "escape the double quote" which means the rest of your code is actually a string that never terminates. In general, inside a string, if you want a literal `\` character, you need to escape it with another `\` because it is itself used for escaping.

You also are closing your `if` statement prematurely. After `if(str.indexOf('"') == -1)` it expects to see an open curly brace or an expression, because the last `)` is closing it out.

This works:

```
if(str.indexOf('"') == -1 || str.indexOf("\\") == -1) {console.log('true')}else{console.log('false');}
```

Neither of these is an Angular or jQuery issue, by the way. These are basic JavaScript syntax issues.